# Getting the NaN rows from pandas.dropna

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I am using dropna to get rid of the NaN values, but instead of just dropping them i want to get a new table where those rows are saved. That's to say from the current code:

```
df_weight.dropna(subset = ["age"], inplace=True)
df_weight.dropna(subset = ["height"], inplace=True)
df_weight.dropna(subset = ["weight"], inplace=True)
df_weight
```

i want to save the rows that are droppen in the line `df_weight.dropna(subset = ["weight"], inplace=True)`. I think that dropna does not have a return value, so there is any work around to archive this?

EDIT: my db comes from https://data.world/bgadoci/crossfit-data/workspace/file?filename=athletes.csv. I deleted all the other rows to make a mini db: after loading the data into pandas i do `df_weight = df[['gender','age','height','weight']]` with the code mentioned above i get something like this (where the desired row datatype is marked)

[image]

Comment: IIUC, you can use `DataFrame.isna()` to identify na rows and put them in another dataframe?

Comment: Could you add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @NorwegianSalmon that gives a true or false database, it changes the values of the table

Comment: @Kevin given the example db now, you could try the inverse of na. Please see if something like this works as I can't test the code as the dataframe is from a link and it's asking an account to access it.

`df_weight.dropna(subset = ["age"], inplace=True)`

`df_na_values = df[~df.index.isin(df_weight.index)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```py
dropped_rows_df =  df_weight[df_weight[['age','height','weight']]].isna().any(axis=1)]

#then
df_weight.dropna(subset = ["age"], inplace=True)
df_weight.dropna(subset = ["height"], inplace=True)
df_weight.dropna(subset = ["weight"], inplace=True)
df_weight
```

Comment: isna has no arguments according to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isna.html#pandas.isna it gives error from each argument incorporated

Comment: Indeed, should have looked at the docs, fixed

Comment: what i actually wanted is only weight to be NaN, so it should be dropped_rows_df =  `df_weight[df_weight[['weight']].isna().any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 0):

you can try as follows. if you share the DF, it will be easier to reproduce and provide the working solution

its an idea or direction

```
df_weight.isna()['age']
df_weight.isna()['height']
df_weight.isna()['weight']
```

Comment: edited my post with the database